# npm ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 while installing electron

Tags: npm, electron, npm-install, node-modules

While installing electron i'm getting this error again and again. I tried different versions, switched from windows to linux, used proxy, changed the registry but the error is occurring again and again

```
> electron@2.0.2 postinstall D:\testingApp\node_modules\electron
> node install.js

Downloading electron-v2.0.2-win32-x64.zip
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 

127.0.0.1:80
D:\testingApp\node_modules\electron\install.js:47
  throw err
  ^

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at ClientRequest.onError (D:\testingApp\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\testingApp\package.json'
npm WARN testingApp No description
npm WARN testingApp No repository field.
npm WARN testingApp No README data
npm WARN testingApp No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron@2.0.2 postinstall: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron@2.0.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```